# ¿Cómo recorro una lista del final al principio?

Tags: java, lista, bucle-for

El programa me imprime lo siguiente:

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Pero debo de hacer que los imprima de esta forma:

```
1
2 1 
3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Necesito ayuda porque es para una tarea, ya llevo mucho tiempo intentado hacerlo y no he podido resolverlo.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
public class Cancion{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 12;
    int valor = 1;

        while (valor <= i){
    
        int j = 1;
    
            while(j <= valor){
        
                System.out.print(j + " ");
                j++;
            }
    
            System.out.println();
            valor++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En el bucle interior, en vez de iterar entre 1 y el valor máximo, itera entre el valor máximo y 1 (orden decreciente).

Answer (score 1):

En cada fila, necesitas empezar en el numero mas alto en lugar de 1. Ese número es el numero de la fila (`valor`). Y luego contar hacia atrás.

```
public class Cancion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 12;
        int valor = 1;

        while (valor <= i) {

            int j = valor; // <-- cambio

            while (j >= 1) { // <-- cambio

                System.out.print(j + " ");
                j--; // <-- cambio
            }

            System.out.println();
            valor++;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas algo como esto, el número de las filas sí va aumentado, pero en el caso de número que se va imprimiendo debe ir disminuyendo.

Cambié el nombre de las variables para que sea un poco más fácil de entenderse.

- `numeroDeFilas` es cuantas filas quieres imprimir.
- `fila` no sirve para saber el número de filas que se van imprimiendo de ahí que fila `<= numeroDeFilas`
- `numero` es el número que se va imprimiendo, como el primero número que se imprime siempre es igual al número de fila en que nos encontramos, por eso `numero = fila`, de ahí que en el segundo while ya solamente tengas que ir decrementando el número para que se imprima en cuenta regresiva.

A continuación dejo como quedaría el código.

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numeroDeFilas = 15;
        int fila = 1;

        while (fila <= numeroDeFilas) {
            int numero = fila;

            while (numero > 0) {
                System.out.print(numero + " ");
                numero--;
            }

            System.out.println();
            fila++;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería otra forma de hacerlo:

```
int start = 1;
int finish = 12;

for (int i = start; i <= finish; ++i) {            
    for (int j = i; j >= start; --j) {
        System.out.print(j+", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

En el segundo bucle le asignamos a las columnas (`j`) el valor de las filas (`i`) y lo vamos decrementando.