# Piramide "invertida"

Tags: java, bucle-for

Estoy haciendo un programa en java que mediante bucles `for`, muestre por pantalla una pirámide numérica como la siguiente:

```
1
2, 1
3, 2, 1
4, 3, 2, 1
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Mi problema esta en que puedo hacer que la salida sea:

```
1
1, 2
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

El fragmento de código es este:

```
Scanner mySc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.printf("%n---Triangle (3)---%n");
System.out.println("Introdueix l'alçada del triangle: ");
int myHeigth = mySc.nextInt();
for (int i = 1; i <= myHeigth; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(j+", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398671/c%C3%B3mo-recorro-una-lista-del-final-al-principio
Me parece que en esta pregunta ya hay respuestas que hacen lo mismo que tú quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Con que cambies el segundo bucle for para que empiece desde el valor máximo y vaya disminuyendo sería sufieciente:

Es decir, cambia esto (2º bucle):

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
```

Por esto:

```
for (int j = i; j >= 1; --j) {
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```
   Scanner mySc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.printf("%n---Triangle (3)---%n");
   System.out.println("Introdueix l'alçada del triangle: ");
   int myHeigth = mySc.nextInt();       
   for (int i = 1; i <= myHeigth; ++i) {            
       for (int j = i; j >= 1; --j) {
            System.out.print(j+", ");
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
```